# How can I debug what role a user is logged in as?

Tags: neoscms

How can I debug what role a user is logged in as?

I'm making a plugin in Neos with front-end users, and want to limit access to certain actions using view-helpers:

```
<f:security.ifHasRole role="Example.Something:User">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In controller, write:

```
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\Flow\Security\Context
 * @Flow\Inject
 */
protected $securityContext;

// In controller action
$this->securityContext->getAccount()
```

And in Fluid view:

```
<f:debug>{account.roles}</f:debug>
```